# Why does my ip-route-add fail silently?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iproute2

I'm trying to configure host A to use a remote Linux server B as the router to Internet. A's eno50332208 has ip address 172.16.100.131. The interface used as gateway on B has address 172.16.100.128.

I use command `ip route add default via 172.16.100.128 dev eno50332208`. But after executing it, nothing changed in routing table. There is no error output in terminal either.

Before the command, `ip route` has only one-line output:

```
172.16.100.0/24 dev eno50332208  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.100.131
```

Why could ip route command fail silently? How can I view the logs/enforce debug info?

Comment: anything in `dmesg | tail` ?

Comment: @FrankThomas Nothing relevant. I tried the `ip route add` command several times and nothing new in `dmesg | tail` output.

Answer (score 0):

If you see a bunch of NetworkManager messages in syslog, NetworkManager overmanaging your connections (running scripts which revert your route changes or re-establishing the connection).

Kill NetworkManager (`killall /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`) and try again